Confidence Intervals, Stopping Conditions, and multiple testing
I am trying to estimate the mean of a random variable distribution using an adaptive sampling procedure with confidence intervals.
I tried using the below:
function adaptive_sampling(max_steps, epsilon, confidence_level):
    data = []
    for i = 1 to max_steps:
        new_point = sample()
        data.append(new_point)
        
        lower, upper = calculate_confidence_interval(data, confidence_level)
        
        if (upper - lower) < epsilon:
            break
    
    return mean(data), (lower, upper), length(data)

that the final confidence interval (lower, upper) returned by this procedure has issues with its confidence level due to multiple testing, because I'm reusing samples.
However, I'm confused about this criticism. My understanding is that the method to calculate confidence intervals is independent of previous calculations. Each time I calculate a new confidence interval, I'm using all the data collected up to that point, which seems valid to me.
Specific questions:
Why does the confidence of my final interval decrease due to the repeated testing in my procedure?
If I'm using all the data for my final confidence interval calculation, how is this different from just collecting that many samples in one go and then calculating the interval?
Does the stopping rule (checking if the interval width is below epsilon) introduce bias into my estimation?
